# EXCEL maintain hyperlink with the cell content after sorting/ using formula

Tags: excel, hyperlink

INTRODUCTION
I have made a excel sheet of file index. Each file entry is linked with scanned copy of the file. So when i click the file name in excel sheet the linked PDF file opens.

ACTIVITY
In a separate worksheet i have made a search function based on multiple search results with partial matching. So when i enter part of either file name or subject i get the file name using

" *=IF($F$1="","",IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$8,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$1,B$2:B$8)),ROW(B$2:B$8)-ROW(B$2)+1),ROWS(B$2:B2))),""))*
"

PROBLEM
The file name obtained is plain text without the hyperlink associated with the file name in the master database.

WHAT HAS BEEN TRIED
I have tried using 
(A)    =IFERROR(HYPERLINK(.....))
(B)    =HYPERLINK(CELL NUMBER)(By getting the row number from formula and using index function to reference the cell)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tiny trick:

Insure the hyperlinks in the source column are formatted so that the "display name" is the URL.  You can use either *Inserted* hyperlinks or the *=HYPERLINK()* worksheet function.

Say we have links in column **A** and we want an alphbetized list in column **C**.  In **B1** enter:

```
=LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(ROWS($1:1),COUNTIF($A$1:$A$3,"<="&$A$1:$A$3)),$A$1:$A$3)
```

and copy downward. *(Column **B** is in alphabetic order, but the links are "cold")* Then in **C1** enter:

```
=HYPERLINK(B1,B1)
```

[image]

Even though the links in column **B** are *"cold"*, the links in column **C** are *"hot"*

Comment: @NileshAthare  Thanks for the feedback!